# Fast load of local images in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I am loading locally stored images that are 640*100 px into a `UITableViewCell`.

The images are loaded asynchronously from disk (on demand), stored to a `NSCache` and then placed into the `UITableViewCell` `UIImageView` on the main thread.

I am experiencing flashing on the cells and some images are not loaded before the cell disappears when scrolling fast. (the scroll speed is greater than the load speed)

I think that I shouldn't load images for cells that will not appear before the cell is reused (when scrolling very fast)

Also, it may be beneficial to store the images "laid out" in memory or even "pre-drawn" but I don't have a good heuristic for both of these problems.

My cells are loading their contents through a data object that is passed in by the UITableView datasource. I don't want the data source to manage fetching of the images because I find the code to be more concise. But now that I am in the optimization stage, this is a problem because the cells don't have a reference to the owner `UITableView` and don't know the scroll speed or other indicators.

Has anyone solved a similar issue? Any way to solve this?

Comment: NSCache,SDWebimage, AFNetworking or other many library that working axpeted that you want do some Google for that.

Comment: please share code where you create cell and load images, this will be a good starting point to help you.

Comment: And are you tried to create low resolution copies of images to load while user scrolls, and then on stop scroll load full resolution images.

Comment: 640*100 px for UITableViewCell Image seems strange resolution normally 30*30 or 60*60 should be fine for a cell image. Blocks dispatch_async is very efficient for loading from local directories or Core Data. Also UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, floatValue); // 0-1 can help to reduce Image Size with compromising quality.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [FastImageCache](https://github.com/path/FastImageCache). It use an ImageTable internally and stores thumnails
in this Table according to the Format specified.